# Appended string buffer to Listview

Tags: java, android, listview

I am trying to use listview format for my android app. I already have all I need in textview. I just want to generate the results on listview. Can anyone here help me please?

If you need futher details please feel free to ask.

Here is my code

```
public void getCallDetails()
{


    String strOder = CallLog.Calls.DATE;
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    Cursor managedCursor = managedQuery( CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI,null, null,null, null);

    int name = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME);
    int number = managedCursor.getColumnIndex( CallLog.Calls.NUMBER );
    int type = managedCursor.getColumnIndex( CallLog.Calls.TYPE );
    int date = managedCursor.getColumnIndex( CallLog.Calls.DATE);
    int duration = managedCursor.getColumnIndex( CallLog.Calls.DURATION);
    sb.append("Call Log:");


    while (managedCursor.moveToNext())
    {


        CallerName = managedCursor.getString(name);
        phoneNumber = managedCursor.getString(number);
        callType = managedCursor.getString(type);
        callDate = managedCursor.getString(date);

        callDateTime = new Date(Long.valueOf(callDate));

        callDuration = managedCursor.getString(duration);


        String cType = null;

        int cTypeCode = Integer.parseInt(callType);

        switch(cTypeCode)
        {
            case CallLog.Calls.OUTGOING_TYPE:
                cType = "OUTGOING";
                break;

            case CallLog.Calls.INCOMING_TYPE:
                cType= "INCOMING";
                break;

            case CallLog.Calls.MISSED_TYPE:
                cType = "MISSED";
                break;
        }


        sb.append("\nCaller Name:"+CallerName +
                "\nPhone Number:"+phoneNumber +
                "\nCall Type:"+cType+" " +
                "\nCall Date:"+callDateTime+" " +
                "\nCall duration in sec :"+callDuration);
        //sb.append("\nPhone Number:--- " + phNumber + " \nCall Type:--- " + dir + " \nCall Date:--- " + callDayTime + " \nCall duration in sec :--- " + callDuration);
        sb.append("\n--------------------------------------------");




    }


    tv.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
   tv.setText(sb);

}
```

Comment: Change to `tv.setText(sb.toString());`

Comment: Thanks for quick response. Tried that. But doesn't work, I guess. What I really need the listview to be clickable.